How to disable distance-grabbing for XR Grab Interactables?
In the Unity default VR template, with XR Interaction Toolkit 3.0, there is a "XR Grab Interactable" component. This allows the user to grab an object with the controller trigger.
This also works when pointing a ray at the object so you can grab it from far away. I cannot figure out how to disable this "far grab" for only certain objects.
If I remove the "Ray" from the controller, the grab doesn't work at all anymore, not even from up close. Also, I don't want to remove "far grab" from ALL interactables. Just from some.
In the screenshot you can see the settings for an interactable, but none seem to be relevant for the allowed grab distance?
On the controller there is "near-far Interactor", but that seem to be generic settings. Also here I don't see how to disable the "far" interaction only.



Have you considered adding a script that sets the XR Grab Interactable to enabled when it enters a trigger radius around the player, and disabled when it leaves?

Well, in the previous XR Interaction Kit you could just drag the "XR Grabbable" component on a cube, and it would do what I expect : only grab it when you can reach it.  But the new system has so many options, I'd rather find out what the correct setting is before writing a workaround.
